# How to project a Lambert conformal conic NetCDF in meters to a longlat grid in R

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I downloaded a Grib file from NOAA that is formatted as a Lambert Conformal Conic with the x/y coordinates given in meters. [Here is the original file.](https://noaa-rrfs-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/rrfs_a/rrfs_a.20231020/12/single_physics/mem0001/rrfs.t12z.testbed.f000.conus_3km.grib2) I've been trying to convert this to longlat grid. I started off by converting it from Grib into NetCDF, which I find easier to work with. Then, I ran the below R code (which is reproducible, if you'd like to try). This feels like a pretty straightforward conversion, but the longitude appears to be way off. For instance, Florida appears to plotted at ~50°W.

My longitude alignment way off -- Where have I gone wrong?

```
library(ncdf4) # package for netcdf manipulation
library(raster) # package for raster manipulation
library(rgdal) # package for geospatial analysis
library(sf) # package for plotting

download.file('https://github.com/guy1996/nc_file_example/raw/eecc0da6c5bfeabfd01f011497d620724bf69ce0/rrfs.t12z.testbed.f000.conus_3km.nc', destfile = basename("./rrfs.t12z.testbed.f000.conus_3km.nc"))
nc_data <- nc_open('rrfs.t12z.testbed.f000.conus_3km.nc')

#pulling variables of interest
x <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "x") 
y <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "y") 
temp <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "2t") # store the data in a 2-dimensional array

#transforming to raster
r <- raster(t(temp), xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y), crs=CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=38.5 +lat_0=38.5 +lon_0=262.5 +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371229 +units=m +no_defs"))
r <- flip(r, direction='y')
plot(r)

#projecting to a longlat grid
r_with_long_latitude <- projectRaster(r, crs='+init=epsg:4269 +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0') 
plot(r_with_long_latitude) #longitude and latitude are not lining up with reality
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NetCDF command line conversion appears to have some issues with this grib format. The grip file was Lambert Conformal Conic in meters. I redid my code to work directly with the grib file, and then, everything worked as expected.

My faulty NetCDF conversion was done via the method in [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501257/how-to-convert-grib1-to-netcdf-using-r).